# TextChange in Gridview Textbox prevent button event

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, button, gridview

I have a text box on a Gridview which I'm allowing some data to be edited. When the enter key is hit, the TextChanged event happens, like I'd expect. But when i change the data and click a button, the button effect not happen. I must click the button again to fire button event. I think it happen because the grid didnot lost it focus.

How to make it possible fire the button event just in one click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your gridview element's `IsTabStop` property to false to gain that effect.

Also if you want to cycle with Tab you can `TabNavigation="Cycle"` .

Both changes are in xaml.

Answer (score 0):

Not much we can do to help you here without the code itself but here are couple things you could try to debug this:

- Try different browsers – it may be a browser issue
- Try some client side debugging – just open console and see if anything happens when you click the button for the first time